# How to change position of gridsplitter if user change it before control loading inside column/row attach to GridSplitter in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```html
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"  Name="Main_Grid" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="1000"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>              
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid Grid.Column="0">
     <UserControl/>
   </Grid>
   <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" ResizeDirection="Columns"           ShowsPreview="False">
   <Grid Grid.Column="2">
       
       
   </Grid>
```

Here is my Grid Structure .

After loading application I set Visibility of UserControl Visible/Collapsed depends on DataContext.

First time FirstColumn take width as per need(as Width property of ColumnDefination is define as "Auto").

But if user move GridSplitter and after that if I assign new Datacontext to User control or click something in UserControl which has different with GridSplitter remain at old position where user left.

How to refresh it so that it First GridColumn Take Width as per need and GridSplitter should appear attach to it.

Comment: You code is incomplete and so hard to understand your problem.

Comment: There is nothing special in my code.But I try to explain.

Comment: .First Column of ColumnDefination has Width="Auto".So First time when I Load Grid it take width as per content and also adjust to the width when I keep changing DataContext of UserControl in Grid.But When I move GridSplitter Some Where after that above behavior of grid destroy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I understand that once the user had changed the position of GridSplitter manually, it will no longer automatically adjust its position even after the size of adjacent Grid changed. In such case, you can revive `Auto` settings of ColumnDefinition by setting it again from code behind.

```
this.Main_Grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = GridLength.Auto;
```

Comment: This is so simple.This work for me.Thank you Emoacht